# Filtering table names that have a same pattern from sqlite database in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a database which I'd like to extract data from tables which have similar name. Lets say I want to filter the tables which have "ABC_DEF" in their names. like: "ABC_DEF_30", "ABC_DEF_40", ....

This code doesn't work for me:
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM TABLES LIKE '+table_name)

I really appreciate if you could help me on this.

Comment: 1. Look up how LIKE works. 2. Look up how to check for tables in SQLite. 3. Look up compound queries.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check for table names that have a certain prefix.

> Quoting [this tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/) about the usage of LIKE in sqlite: The percentage sign `%` wildcard matches
>   any sequence of zero or more characters.

So your pattern really is

```
pattern = '%s%' % prefix
```

but because `%` is an operator in python strings you need to escape it by setting it to

```
pattern = '%s%%' % prefix
```

A full code would look like this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_connection_string)
c = conn.cursor()
q = 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" and name LIKE "%s%%";' % prefix
c.execute(q)
```